# django - get all objects in one table which do not have a foreignkey in another table

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 2 models:

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    person1 = models.ForeignKey("Person", related_name="friend1")
    person2 = models.ForeignKey("Person", related_name="friend2")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

class Person(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
```

I want a list of `Person` objects which do not have any entries in the `Friend` object. e.g.

```
no_friends = Person.objects.filter(????)
```

but I'm not sure what the filter should be.

Comment: Naming tip: your Friend class should really be called `Friendship`, as it's modelling the *relationship* between two friends.

Comment: you might wanna look at this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to use the related manager.

```
no_friends = Person.objects.filter(friend1=None,friend2=None)
```