# Django ORM equivalent to left exclusive JOIN

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-views

Relatively new to Django and I have the following models in my django (3.2) project:

```
class projectsA(models.Model):
    projectID_A = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    project_name_A = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    project_desc_A = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    projectID_B = models.ForeignKey('projectsB', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='projectID_B', blank=True, null=True, db_constraint=False)

    class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'projectsA'

class projectsB(models.Model):
    projectID_B = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    project_name_B = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    project_desc_A = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
      managed = False
      db_table = 'projectsB'
```

I want to get all projects from projectsA which are not in projectsB. The SQL equivalent would be

```
SELECT * FROM projectsA a LEFT JOIN projectsB b on a.projektID_B = b.projectID_B WHERE b.projectID_B is null
```

I have tried with .exclude or .select_related() and several other approaches, but cannot find a solution for this scenario. Thanks in advance.

Comment: does this solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780440/django-get-all-objects-in-one-table-which-do-not-have-a-foreignkey-in-another

Comment: Thanks. If I understood correct, that problem there is a bit reversed. Here the question is, which objects do not have a pk in table b but have entry in fk column in table a.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
queryset = projectsA.objects.filter(projektID_B__isnull=True)
```

You can read about `isnull` here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#isnull

Comment: Thanks. I thought so, too. But it isn't giving me the expected results (no case, instead of the one the query yields) and if I understood correctly this syntax will use foreign-key relation to go to "projectsB"-table and then look for nulls in related field , which is of course none in pk-column "projects_ID_B". I just saw, that I had a typo in my question: Should be always projects_ID_B (instead of projekts_ID_B). Sorry.